# Why do I get "package not found" when trying to install jabref with apt-get?

Tags: command-line, package-management

I can find a particular application 'JabRef' at the ubuntu software centre. But whenever I type `sudo apt-get install jabref` in terminal, it says package not found. What's going wrong here? Do I have to capitalise the exact letters as in the application name or do I need some additional steps to make sure the terminal looks at the correct repository for the particular installer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Execute `sudo apt-get update` first and then try installing jabref again.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure that `Universe` repository is available in software sources as here . Tick mark it if Unticked initially.

[image]

Then do `sudo apt-get update & sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Check if `jabref` is present by  **`apt-cache show jabref`**.

And finally **`sudo apt-get install jabref`** . No capitalization of any word is required however.

Comment: Command line version of this:  `sudo add-apt-repository universe`