# How can I use classic menu in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, menu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to revert to GNOME Classic?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic)

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04, and it's with Gnome 3 and does not have classic menu like 10.04. Is there any way to have classic menu in 12.04 and any way to switch back and forth when I like to?

Comment: Try installing gnome-session-fallback from the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: tried but failed see error description:
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback
[sudo] password for gmuhammad: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package gnome-session-fallback is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'gnome-session-fallback' has no installation candidate

Comment: see answer to question 122437
http://askubuntu.com/questions/122437/how-to-access-applications-menu-in-ubuntu-unity-desktop

Comment: @gmuhammad - It seems that your `Universe` Repository is Disabled ,refer [this image](http://askubuntu.com/a/172460/63025) to enable it , run `sudo apt-get update` and try installing it.

Comment: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/6/applications-menu/